# Change value of asp:BoundField as page loads

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following:

```
<Columns>
    ...
    <asp:BoundField DataField="datetime_added" HeaderText="When Added" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="datetime_added" />
    ...
</Columns>
```

The `DataField` `datetime_added` comes from a SQL Data Source.  I want to do some editing of every value for this column after the values are queried from the SQL Data Source on the C# side. Kind of like:

```
//short pseudo code example
protected void someEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    sender.GetField["datetime_added"] = "test";
}
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Do you want to edit the values before being bound to the gridview or after the fact upon a button click or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use a templatefield instead of a boundfield
- with a label
- the label text is fed by a function throught something like this:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" EnableModelValidation="True">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%= SomeFunction(Eval("db_id"),Eval("description")) %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

And this in your code behind:

```
protected string SomeFunction(object id, object description)
{
    //your code
    return "";
}
```

When your function is called, the field from SQL is passed as an object
so that you can use it if you want or return something else based on whatever you want.

The function is called when the value is bound from the datasource in each row, you'll probably need to pass an id as well to identify the row.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the "OnRowCreated" event? I'm assuming here that you're using a GridView, and if not, then there may be something similar in whatever component it is you're binding the data to.

For GridView, here is an example:

```
protected void gridView1_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        // do what you need in here
        // e.Row.Cells[x] where x = the column number
    }
}
```

Also, this method can be really slow depending on how many rows you're processing.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `RowDataBound` event to manipulate the values before it's being bound to the grid (getting called while binding every row to the gridview)

```
protected void Gridview1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
       string datetimeadded = DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "datetime_added").ToString();

       // or you can use the cell index to reference the boundfield like below
       string datetimeadded = e.Row.Cells[1].Text;
    }
}
```